# How can I create a countdown timer in an app that persists if the app is closed?

Tags: java, android, time

I am creating a game which uses "Energy points" as a currency to do certain actions in the game (you have to spend energy points to do certain tasks).  When the player reaches zero energy points, or does not have enough energy to do a certain task, I they should wait a few hours in order to continue, or watch a video in order to get some quick points.

This should have the following features:

I've created a PopupDialog  using the following code.  The function `showPopupDialog()` is naturally called if the condition `energyCost < energyPoints`.

```
 public void showPopupDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Not Enough Energy!");
        dialog.setMessage("You don't have enough Energy Points to do this! 
 Would you like to watch a video to get more Energy?");
        ((AlertDialog.Builder) dialog).setPositiveButton("Watch", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //ad plays here  
                energyPoints = energyPoints + 500;
                ep.setText(energyPoints+"");
            }
        });
        ((AlertDialog.Builder) dialog).setNegativeButton("Wait", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        energyPoints = energyPoints+500;
                        ep.setText(energyPoints+"");
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }
```

I would like to know how to make the following modifications:

- The countdown timer should persist even though the app is closed or I navigate away from the activity.  So that when I come back in 4 hours, some energy points will be restored.
- You cannot click on "Wait" (thus triggering another timer) while a current timer is in progress.  You have to wait for the alloted time before you can click it again.
- The game sends a notification when the waiting is over so that the player knows to continue.

Comment: store persistent when the last energy point restored, when you resume app - check how much time passed, and add corresponding energy

Answer (score 0):

To be accurate the easiest way would be a server/client interaction so that you can't just manipulate the time by setting it to 4h later.

If manipulating is okay for you - just read/write the latest time set in an external file.

Comment: Thanks, I actually hadn't thought of that.  My app is fairly simple and most of it is done on the client side so far.  But yeah, I guess I could also use some other way of getting the time so that they can't cheat the system.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing a lot of the code, I will suggest a concept.

Use the timer itself for a presentational purpose, but for a real working logic, create a timestamp of "last poinst added", or something like that.

This will allow you to, every time you need to use, show or get actual points, grab the last timestamp, compare it with the current time, and act accordingly. For example, I check the last one, and when compared, the difference is 3h. If every ten minutes I have 5 points, I'll do 3*60/10 * 5 = total points earned.

This will allow to just focus on the fact that time has passed, instead of making a timer.

Then, when the application closes, you store the last timestamp, and when reopened, compare it again and act accordingly.